# Convert an existing Keystore to an android debug keystore for eclipse

Tags: android, adt, keystore, android-keystore

Sometimes it might be handy to use an **existing** keystore in eclipse (Android -> Build -> CustomKeystore) to build from within eclipse.

The Eclipse plugin does not allow to change the keystore password, key-alias and key password though.

Is there a way to convert an existing keystore to match the default requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following keytool commands should do the trick. There definitly is a simpler way, but it already took enough time figuring this one out :)

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
keytool -delete -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore src.keystore -destkeystore debug.keystore
keytool -changealias -alias srcalias -destalias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore
keytool -keypasswd -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore
```

- This creates a new keystore and imports an existing key from a source keystore
- keystore. src.keystore -> your source keystore that will be used
- srcalias -> your source alias you're currently using
- passwords are entered on cmdline

use 'keytool -list -keystore debug.keystore' to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

Very useful information, should be voted up. I wrote a small batch file basing on Icyerasor's answer:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -storepass android -keypass android -dname "CN=kristjan sander, OU=Unknown, O=bitspinners, L=tallinn, ST=Unknown, C=ee"
keytool -delete -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jsk -srcstorepass qwerty -destkeystore debug.keystore -storepass android
keytool -changealias -alias bitspinners.eu -destalias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass qwerty
keytool -keypasswd -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass qwerty -new android
keytool -list -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android
```